# Button error in android studio. Written in java but shows error. What should i do?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have enabled a button as well as a textField on Android studio.

The button returns the value on logs but somehow the code i've written for the textField returns an error.

Code as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public void button (View view){
    EditText textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView);// this line is an error.
    Log.i("i","info");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are trying to cast `TextView` into `EditText` which is not possible

If you want to take input from the user then `EditText` is your choice

If you want to show some text then `TextView` should fit your requirements

**Solution**

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Comment: Glad to hear, then please consider vote up as well for the answer, thanks